# Como fazer soma móvel no R?

Tags: array, r, data-manipulation

Tenho um vetor `1:50` e preciso realizar uma soma móvel (igual a média móvel), isto é, no caso das ultimas 5 observação, o novo vetor seria `c(sum(1:5), sum(2:6), sum(3:7), ..., sum(45:49), sum(46:50))`.
 A função aggregate tem exemplo `aggregate(presidents, nfrequency = 1, FUN = weighted.mean, w = c(1, 1, 0.5, 1))` que foi o mais perto que eu cheguei da solução sem usar um `for`

Comment: Com o pacote `zoo`, tente `rollsum(presidents, k = 5)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conheço dois pacotes bons para fazer isso. O `zoo` (como o Rui citou no comentário) e o `RcppRoll`.

```
> zoo::rollsum(1:20, k = 5)
 [1] 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90
> RcppRoll::roll_sum(1:20, n = 5)
 [1] 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60 65 70 75 80 85 90
```

Em questão de performance, o `RcppRoll` é **muito** mais rápido:

```
> bench::mark(
+   zoo::rollsum(1:50, k = 5),
+   RcppRoll::roll_sum(1:50, n = 5)
+ )
# A tibble: 2 x 14
  expression     min     mean  median    max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result memory time  gc   
  <chr>      <bch:t> <bch:tm> <bch:t> <bch:>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis> <lis>
1 zoo::roll… 909.4µs   3.45ms  1.71ms 40.3ms      290.   18.91KB     0   155      535ms <int … <Rpro… <bch… <tib…
2 RcppRoll:…  40.5µs 150.75µs 89.49µs 14.6ms     6634.    3.34KB     0  3316      500ms <dbl … <Rpro… <bch… <tib…
```

Comment: Boa! Na verdade o `zoo` perde até para o `base` em performance.

Answer (score 4):

Há algumas maneiras que você pode calcular a soma móvel no [r](/questions/tagged/r):

## R-base

```
diff(c(0, cumsum(1:10)), 5)
# 15 20 25 30 35 40
```

Essa proposta pode ser generalizada como função:

```
soma_movel <- function(x, n) {
  diff(c(0, cumsum(x)), n)
}
```

## Zoo

O pacote `zoo`, como levantado nos comentários, tem uma função para isso, mas ela não desempenha muito bem

```
zoo::rollsum(1:10, 5)
# 15 20 25 30 35 40
```

## Comparação

```
set.seed(123)
vetor <- rnorm(1e5) # 100 mil números

# As funções retornam valores iguais?
all.equal(zoo::rollsum(vetor, 5), soma_movel(vetor, 5))
# [1] TRUE
```

Por fim, uma comparação na performance das soluções levantadas demonstra que mesmo sendo mais cerca de 80 vezes mais rápida do que com o `zoo`, a solução com o `base` ainda perde para a solução com o `RcppRoll` apresentada pelo Daniel em 5 vezes.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  zoo = zoo::rollsum(vetor, 5),
  base = soma_movel(vetor, 5), 
  cpp = RcppRoll::roll_sum(vetor, n = 5),
  times = 30
)
Unit: microseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
  zoo 200659.545 204218.475 208418.887 206276.601 209928.673 255552.267    30   b
 base   2229.273   2536.157   3379.694   2633.918   2755.286   7725.985    30  a 
  cpp    452.116    514.725   6966.097    558.089    577.333 188068.577    30  a
```